# Select distinct from table into temp then reload temp back into main table

Tags: dynamic, insert-into

I'm struggling with the syntax of how to do dynamic sql for this.

What I am trying to do

- select distinct records from a main table
- Put those records into a temp table
- Clear the records from the main table
- then select the distinct data from the temp back into the main table

I am already checking the main tables and populating a temp table with a list of tables that have duplicate data.

Then by looping through each row in that temp table to see what tables are duplicate, using a cursor, I wanted to use the actual table name, which is loaded into a variable, to then select the **distinct** records from this table into a another temp table.

Then I want to clear the main table and reload the distinct data from temp back into the main table.

This is the statement before cursor that loads the first temp table with the table name that has duplicates

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP_TBL_DUP_CNT
select cast(@rec_cnt as varchar(10)) reccnt, cast(@tbl_name as varchar(200)) 
tblnm
```

So this is my cursor below and i have numbered my ideas below 1-4 as related to bullet list above. The syntax is the bit I am struggling with and would like help as to how to create it.

```
DECLARE REC_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
-- Set select stamtent for cursor

select reccnt, tblnm
from #TEMP_TBL_DUP_CNT

OPEN REC_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM REC_CURSOR INTO @rec_cnt, @tbl_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 

-- Check if record count is 0
-- if is larger than 0 then select distinct records from tbl name into
-- temp table

if @rec_cnt > 0

-- Need to load data into new temp table using dynamic SQL and @tbl_name 
-- Ideally wanted to create a temp Table with dynamic name like 
-- '#TEMP_' + @tbl_name giving #temp_Table_Name_1, #temp_Table_Name_2 etc.
-- 

 1) Starting with something like :

-- SET @tbl_temp = '#TEMP_' + @tbl_name

 2) Then select distinct * into temp like this:

-- SELECT 'distinct * INTO ' + @tbl_temp + ' FROM ' + @tbl_name

 3) Then clear main table

-- TRUNCATE TABLE + '@tbl_name'

 4) Then select from temp back into main table

-- SELECT '* INTO ' + @tbl_name + ' FROM ' + @tbl_temp

FETCH NEXT FROM REC_CURSOR INTO @rec_cnt, @tbl_name
END

CLOSE REC_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE REC_CURSOR
```

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Why you want to do this instead of rename the original as backup, rename the temp as the new origin table?

Comment: @mootmoot Ok, I never had the back up at the front of my mind, more the dynamic SQL, I can tack that on as part of the process, makes sense.

Comment: Don't forget to recreate the index after you do the rename on the temp tables .

Comment: @mootmoot I don't have an index on it at the moment

Comment: Can anyone help with the actual Dynamic SQL such as how to do insert, select etc?

Comment: Can no one provide an idea how to build the dynamic sql in this?